# How do I compare the timedelta between 2 columns of a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have 2 rows of data that look like the following (rows 8 and 9) ....

```
 2018-01-03T10:14:32.000Z
 2018-01-03T09:40:35.000Z
 2018-01-03T10:17:13.000Z
 2018-01-03T10:00:39.000Z
 2018-01-03T10:16:53.000Z
 2018-01-03T09:54:24.000Z
 2018-01-03T10:18:37.000Z
 2018-01-03T10:19:54.000Z
 2018-01-03T09:52:40.000Z
 2018-01-03T10:14:49.000Z
 2018-01-03T10:16:35.000Z
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Plaku_City_Service_Requests_in_2018.csv', 
                 usecols = [8,9],
                 names = ['add', 'fix'])

df['delta'] = df['add'] - df['fix']
```

I am getting errors

There are 330,000 entries in this CSV file .. how do I find the timedeltas between these 2 columns?

I have these two columns stored in variables add and fix.. cant figure out how to compare.

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.  You refer to both two rows and two columns of data.  You've posted something that looks like a single column, that being a time stamp.  What sort of value do you expect to see as the difference between a date and a time-of-day?

Comment: Your basic request seems to be a direct time difference of some sort.  Time difference is covered quite well in on-line tutorials dealing with the `datetime` package.  Where is the code that has you stuck?

Comment: import datetime as datetime
import pandas as pd



df=pd.read_csv('Plaku_City_Service_Requests_in_2018.csv', usecols = [8,9], names = ['add', 'fix'])

df['delta'] = df['add'] - df['fix']

Comment: Edit your clarifications into the question, please.  As you can see, code does not appear nicely in comments.

Comment: I tried the code in the answer below and I got more errors

Answer (score 1):

It would seem appropriate to read both columns from the CSV into one DataFrame, rather than two separate ones:

```
df = pd.read_csv('2018.csv', usecols=[8, 9], names=['add', 'fix'])
```

If Pandas correctly infers that the type of your data is datetime, then finding the deltas is as simple as:

```
df['delta'] = df['add'] - df['fix']
```

If however they are inferred as strings, you will need to explicitly convert to datetime objects before the subtraction:

```
df['delta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['add']) - pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```